# htaccess file configuration Multiple <Files> arguments not (yet) supported

Tags: php, .htaccess

So... I need a little help from the professionals (that would would be you awesome bunch).

I'm working on creating a php site... It's in the development stages but it doesn't work yet.  I get this message when I try to access the site:

> > "*Internal Server Error. The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. More information about this error may be available in the server error log.*"

This is what is said in the error log:

> > "[Tue Aug 05 08:13:11.968355 2014] [core:alert] [pid 1264:tid 140197817698048] [client 206.183.14.57:46764] /home/some directory/public_html/dev/.htaccess: Multiple  arguments not (yet) supported."

I've never created an HTACCESS file before - ever.  And I used an [online HTACCESS generator](http://htaccesser.apacheblog.de/index-nojs.php) to do this one.  I don't know what may or may not be wrong with it, but here it is:

> **NOTE, there will be streaming media on this site from time to time which is why I have some of those "types" in there**

```
#htaccess file
#http://dev.mysite.com
#I really hope this works right.

AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile http://dev.mysite.com/members/index.php
Order deny,allow
Require valid-user

AddType application/x-httpd-php          php php4
AddType application/x-httpd-php3         php3
AddType application/x-javascript         js
AddType application/x-shockwave-flash    swf
AddType application/x-sprite             spr sprite
AddType application/xls                  xls
AddType audio/x-mpeg                     mp2 mp3
AddType audio/x-ms-wma           wma
AddType audio/x-pn-realaudio             ram ra rm
AddType audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin      rpm
AddType audio/x-qt-stream                stream
AddType audio/x-wav                      wav
AddType image/gif                        gif
AddType image/jpeg                       jpeg jpg jpe
AddType image/png            png
AddType image/tiff                       tiff tif
AddType image/x-ms-bmp                   bmp
AddType text/css             css
AddType text/html                        htm html
AddType text/xml             xml
AddType video/mpeg                       mpeg mpg mpe
AddType video/quicktime                  qt mov
AddType video/x-msvideo                  avi
<Files .htaccess .htpasswd .htuser .htgroups .ini .config >
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

RewriteEngine  on    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(dev\.)?mysite.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png|mp3|mpg|avi|mov)$ - [F]  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Wget [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} CherryPickerSE [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} CherryPickerElite [OR] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} EmailCollector [OR]  #DENY EMAIL HARVESTERS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} EmailSiphon [OR]     #DENY EMAIL HARVESTERS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} EmailWolf [OR]   #DENY EMAIL HARVESTERS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ExtractorPro     #DENY EMAIL HARVESTERS
RewriteRule ^.*$ deny.html [L]  #DENY EMAIL HARVESTERS

RewriteRule    ^Members/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$    index.php?username=$1    [NC,L]    # Process UserName

ErrorDocument 401 403.html  #Authentication Required/Forbidden
ErrorDocument 403 403.html  #Authentication Required/Forbidden
ErrorDocument 404 404.html  #File Not Found
ErrorDocument 500 500.html  #Server Error

DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Can someone tell me what I did wrong? (other than visit an online generator?)  And how to fix it?

ANY help would be appreciated.
-Thanks